# Can't reach QuickSight from aws-sdk-js: QuickSight is not a constructor

Tags: webpack, aws-sdk-js, amazon-quicksight

I'm kinda new to JS and trying to build a web site to provide an internal GUI to interact with the QuickSight API. I npm installed aws-sdk-js to it's latest version (2.798.0) but I got an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: _awsSdk2.default.QuickSight is not a constructor

when I tried to create a new instance with `new AWS.QuickSight();`

I'm using Webpack and importing the library like this `import AWS from 'aws-sdk'`. When I `console.log(AWS)` in the output I can see a lot of AWS services, but QuickSight is not one of them.

Here are the versions that I'm working with

```
    "aws-sdk": "^2.798.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.6.0"
```

I [had read that](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/webpack.html) it was necessary to add json-loader to the webpack config, but [I also found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49373676) that it was no longer needed since version 2.0.0 of webpack.

Tried with [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2794#issuecomment-522886306) approach as well, but didn't have any luck either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems when QuickSight was included into AWS SDK it was included in some unusual way unlike other packages (probably to avoid aws-sdk bloat).

If you import QuickSight client specifically then it should work

```
import QuickSight from 'aws-sdk/clients/quicksight'
```

Answer (score 0):

Following `aws-sdk-js-v3` found [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/tree/main/clients/client-quicksight). First, you need to import the client:

`import { QuickSightClient, GetDashboardEmbedUrlCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-quicksight";`

Then, your function code would look like the following:

```
const quicksight = new QuickSightClient({
    region: 'REGION',
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: 'KEY_ID',
        secretAccessKey: 'SECRET_KEY'
    }
});

const command = new GetDashboardEmbedUrlCommand(params);

try {
    const data = await quicksight.send(command);
    return {
        props: { url: data.EmbedUrl }
    };
} catch (err) {
    console.log('err', err)
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell where `accessKeyId: 'KEY_ID'` can be found?

Comment: @MaksatRahmanov this would be the IAM user you setup with permissions to invoke Quicksight commands